# Why does 'setprecision' not get exactly the decimal number?

Tags: c++, floating-point

This is my code in Visual Studio Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        sum += double(1.0 / i);
    }
    std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed << sum;
}
```

```
input: 10
Output: 2.9290
```

I use my calculator to calculate but the answer is 2.9289. Why the result is rounded automatically?

I hope someone can explain this problem to me and make a clear explanation.

Comment: Not even reading the description of the tag you used?

Comment: OT: Please don't use macros like `F`, or global variables. Those are both very bad habits. And don't save you much time either writing or executing the code, much less than you probably expect. And make your code close to undebugable and unmaintainable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: ... and I was pretty lost when I was trying to read and understand the code. It violates the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: When you write a [mre], please replace user input by hard coded numbers whenever possible. It is possible here. That way people trying to help you can't do it wrong. And you eliminated a potential source of mistake on your side as well.

Comment: Also, the explicit conversion in `double(1.0 / i)` is not needed. Because you use the `double` constant `1.0` the result of `1.0 / i` will already be of type `double`.

Comment: Try `std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed << 2.92896825`, or alternatively, how would you print `2.92896825` with above precision?

Comment: And perhaps a little read about [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) might help? It *rounds* to four decimal digits, and there are likely decimal digits beyond the four you expect that leads to that rounding.

Comment: I don't know what calculator you have, but https://godbolt.org/z/r1oe7xP6f gives a nice clue. 2.9289 is not an accurate result.

Comment: Minor point: formally, output from a C or C++ program must end with a newline. So add `<< '\n';` to that output line. In practice it doesn't usually matter; you won't be running on IBM mainframes, which is where the rule was essential. On the other hand, you won't be plagued by strange `%` signs after your output, which happens in some terminals when there is no newline on the output: the terminal prompt simply gets appended to the output.

Comment: *Why the result is rounded automatically?*  I'm even more curious as to why does your calculator truncate automatically?

Comment: @Cigs "I use my calculator to calculate but the answer is 2.9289" --> C code and output are OK.  You need a better calculator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of the first ten reciprocals is `7381 / 2520`. That's with full mathematical precision, assuming *no* imperfections in floating-point arithmetic. Written as a decimal, that number is approximately `2.92896825397`. We want to *round* this to four decimal places. Rounding is different than truncating. *Truncating* involves simply chopping off the remaining digits. But rounding looks at the following digit to see what to do.

```
2.92896825397
      ^
      Look here to see what to do
```

Six is greater than five, so we round up. We increase the `9` in the fourth place, causing the extra digit to carry over and increase the `8` in the third decimal place.

```
2.9290
```

And there's your answer. This is the decimal with four digits after the decimal point which is closest in value to the real solution.